Question regarding the degree of dissociation and dissociation constant
Question:  Limiting molar conductivities of NH4Cl, NaOH and NaCl are respectively 129.8, 217.4 and
108.9 Scm2mol-1.If the conductivity of 10-2 M NH4OH is 9.33 x 10-5 Scm-1, calculate the degree of dissociation and dissociation constant of NH4OH.
I cant find the answer online, so I came here.
I found the limiting molar conductivity of Nh4OH = 129.8 + 217.4 - 108.9 = 238.3
Molar conductivity = (K/M) * 1000 = 9.33 * 10^-5 * 1000/10^-2 = 9.33
Degree of dissociation(α) = Molar conductivity / limiting molar conductivity = 9.33 / 238.3 = 0.3
Dissociation constant = Cα^2/1-α = 10^-2 * 0.03 * 0.03/ 0.97.
Can this value come, it seems so small. I feel like I made some error somewhere

There is NH3(aq), NH4+(aq), OH-(aq), but no NH4OH(aq) nor NH4OH(s,l). //
It is always good to summarize and/or complement the verbal description  by describing the problem/task with symbolic algebraic expressions. And, keeping it that way until all is ready to just plug-in literal numbers with units. It helps in focusing on principles, mistakes are easier to spot, orientation is improved, Q/A is reusable and has bigger  permanent value.

Also, when working with literal values, it is mandatory to use them with their units. E.g. 1000 mL = 1 L, but 1000 <> 1.
